# Remplazar un Carácter de una posición "X" de un String

Tags: java, string, eclipse

Necesito remplazar la posición 0 y 1 de una variable String por dos ceros, pero me salta error el código texto.SetCharAt(0,"0");

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String texto;

    System.out.println("Ingrese un el 1r Texto");
    texto = scan.nextLine();

    if (texto.length() > 10) {

        System.out.println("Su palabra tiene más de 10 Carácteres");

        texto.SetCharAt(0,"0");
        texto.SetCharAt(1,"0");

        System.out.println("Su NUEVA palabra es: "+texto);

    }

    else {
        System.out.println("Su palabra tiene: "+texto.length()+" Carácteres");
    }
}
```

Comment: por que las etiquetas javascript y chart.js?

Comment: Lo siento, solo quería ser lo más especifico posible, soy un poco nuevo en esto. Gracias por la corrección.

Comment: entiendo que bueno te quedo pero no veo la necesidad de mezclar cosas que no tienen que ver, pues java no es lo mismo que javascript asi que no tenian sentido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

me queda la duda si deseas agregar los dos ceros o reemplazar lo que existe en la pocision. Te doy dos ejemplos para concatenar y agregarle los dos ceros es casi:

```
String texto = "1234567890";
String a = "00";    
String resultado = a + texto;
```

Para reemplazar en posicion

```
StringBuilder texto= new StringBuilder("texto123");
myName.setCharAt(0, 'x');

System.out.println(myName);
```

en tu código debes usar el StringBuilder y comillas simples para el valor a reemplazar

Comment: por qure parte de tu respuesta esta en inglés?

Comment: perdon estaba respondieron en los dos stackoverflow y me cruce de idiomas

Answer (score 1):

Si siempre reemplazaras los primeros 2 caracteres de la cadena podria ser

```
if (str.length()>10) {
    str = "00" + str.substring(2, str.length());
}
```

O usando StringBuilder

```
if (str.length()>10) {
    StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder(str);
    stb.setCharAt(0, '0');
    stb.setCharAt(1, '0');
    str = stb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por convención todos los métodos en java se comienzan a nombrar en minúscula, por lo tanto si es un método que tu mismo defines debes nombrarlo como setCharAt. En este caso imagino que pertenece a la clase String y dado que java distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, los métodos setChartAt y SetCharAt no son los mismos a ojos del compilador. Debes cambiar el método a setChartAt.

Comment: ¿Y que método debería utilizar? He probando con replace y no da el resultado que busco.

Comment: @Alejandro Acabo de mirar y la clase String no tiene el método setCharAt, la clase que dispone de ese método es StringBuilder

Comment: Cambié la clase texto a StringBuilder y no me cambió nada, el setCharAt me salta el mismo error. Alguna otra solución? :(